# How does the asm code offer the function of fence

Tags: java, assembly, jvm

See the following code:

```
inline void OrderAccess::fence() {
  if (os::is_MP()) {//judge if the os is muti processor.
    // always use locked addl since mfence is sometimes expensive
#ifdef AMD64
    __asm__ volatile ("lock; addl $0,0(%%rsp)" : : : "cc", "memory");
#else
    __asm__ volatile ("lock; addl $0,0(%%esp)" : : : "cc", "memory");
#endif
  }
}
```

How does the code offer the function of 'fence'?

The code is from jdk8/openjdk/hotspot/src/os_cpu/bsd_x86/vm/orderAddress_bsd_x86.inline.hpp

Plus what does 'cc' clobber mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter 8.2.2 *"Memory Ordering"* of [Intel Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.ru/content/www/ru/ru/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) says that locked instructions have a total order, no reads or writes can be reordered with locked instructions.

David Dice explains in [his blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/entry/instruction_selection_for_volatile_fences) why `LOCK ADD`  has been chosen instead of `MFENCE` instruction.

`cc` *(condition codes)* clobber indicates that the flags register is modified.

Comment: Hello，Thanks to your answer firstly,but I want to know the meaning of the Code,I want to know what does "lock; addl $0,0(%%esp)" : : : "cc", "memory" represent?@apangin

Comment: @yangyixiaof This instruction does nothing except memory ordering. It literally means *"atomically add zero to the value on the top of stack"* (or the same in C syntax: `volatile intptr_t tos; tos += 0;`)